# How to list items from unlimited $_POST variables like paypal?

Tags: php, post

I Want to receive items details using $_POST and list them like an invoice (exactly like paypal) So if i receive:

```
item_name = Flowers
item_description = Alicia Flowers Store
item_quantity = 3

item_name1 = Twilight
item_description1 = Main Library
item_quantity1 = 1

item_name2 = GTA IV
item_description2 = Rock Star
item_quantity2 = 1
```

I'de end up with a php array like this:

```
productsnames(Flowers,Twilight,GTA IV)
productsdesc(Alicia Flowers Store,Main Library,Rock Star)
productsquantities(3,1,1)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$productsnames = array();
$productsdesc = array();
//...
foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) {
    if (preg_match('/^item_name(?:_\\d+)?$/', $k, $matches)) {
        $productsnames[] = $v;
    }
    //...
}
```

This assumes everything is in order. If it's not, you could use `$matches[1]` (and set it to `0` if inexistent) as the key for the result arrays. After that, you would probably want to sort the result arrays with `ksort`.